# Data sent to email on HTML form submit

Tags: html, forms, web

I want to create a feedback form where the users input data and when they press submit button, all the data entered is received by the admin at an email address which has been predefined in the code.
i don't want to use "mailto" as it opens another service. Is there any way to send data to email through the HTML form itself?

Answer (score 0):

Forms send data to the URL specified in the `action` attribute.

`mailto:` URLs, which you have sensibly ruled out, [are highly unreliable](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html).

The only other kind of URL which can be usefully used is an `http(s)` URL where it is then processed by server side code.

If you want to send the emails to a different address then you need to change the server side code so it doesn't use a single address.

Comment: I do not want server side processing. The data will not go to the server and directly to the admin's email

Comment: @FedoraExplores — As I said in this answer, that isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I have decided to use https://formsubmit.co for this purpose. The details are present in their documentation.
It was exactly what I wanted, and completes my requirements. Thank you to everyone for their help.